# How to this Complex problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $$p(z)=A_n z^n+A_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+A_1z+A_0,$$ then $p(w_1)=0,p(w_2)=0,\dots,p(w_n)=0$. Why $w_1+w_2+\dots +w_n=-\frac{A_{n-1}}{A_n}$?

I understand only Real part. But I don't know the Complex part.

Answer (score 0):

The complex argument is the same as the real one.  Write $p(z)=A_n(z-w_1)(z-w_2)\dots (z-w_n)$ and imagine multiplying it out.  You get $p(z)=A_nz^n-\sum_iw_iz^{n-1}+\dots$